# Erro: "Não foi possível encontrar o símbolo BookmarkColumns"

Tags: android

Tenho um projeto de 3 anos atras e preciso fazer ele voltar a vida, porem é cheio de complicações com atualizações, me deparei com um impace que a Browser Bookmark Changes foi removida.

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

Nessa método que estou usando a chamada do `Browser.BookmarkColumns`:

```
@Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id) {
    Adapter adapter = getListAdapter();
    if (position >= 0 && position < adapter.getCount()) {
      String packageName = ((AppInfo) adapter.getItem(position)).getPackageName();
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
      intent.putExtra(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, "market://details?id=" + packageName);
      setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    } else {
      setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);      
    }
    finish();
  }
```

Em outro lugares eu também faço a chamada desse `Browser.BookmarkColumns` ou do `Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema provavelmente é que, com as "actualizações", foi declarado o `compileSdkVersion` para a versão 6.0 ou superior.

A versão 6.0 remove a compatibilidade com "favoritos globais".

[Extracto da documentação:](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser)

> Esta versão remove a compatibilidade com favoritos globais. Os métodos android.provider.Browser.getAllBookmarks() e android.provider.Browser.saveBookmark() foram removidos. Da mesma forma, as permissões READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS e WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS foram removidas. Se o aplicativo for voltado ao Android 6.0 (API de nível 23) ou posterior, não acesse as marcações do provedor global nem use as permissões de adição aos favoritos. Em vez disso, o aplicativo deve armazenar internamente os favoritos.

Ou declara `compileSdkVersion=22` ou a sua aplicação terá de guardar/gerir os seus *Bookmarks*

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de como teria de alterar meu código onde esta tentando salvar o favoritos com o Bookmarks para fazer isso local?

Comment: Terá eventualmente de usar o Sqlite. Existem muitos exemplos de como usá-lo, é só procurar.